# fill data from one dataframe to another with criteria then repeatedly fill till criteria changes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So the run down:

I have two dataframes in the same calendar year but different temporal average daily. DF1 is minutetly and DF2 is daily.

**Directive**

I now am thinking of using a 'days since' criteria  days = 1,2,3....i and place all the columns from DF2 into DF1 and filling each individual proceeding row in that day with repeat of that dayily avaraged date then move onto the next day!

- I have two files they're both CSV files.
- These will be read into pandas as CSV files converted to dataframes.
- I'm thinking of starting over, code below is first attempt with
  associating minutely to hourly data
- Add a days since September 12 2014 column and do something if
  df[days] = df1[days] print the columns from df(in this example this
  is the daily avg) df1( this is the 3min averaged data)

I have this sample of code below associating hourly data to minutely data.

Tab separated examples:

```
Date    Pressure    Temperature Salinity    Density
9/12/2014   20.67517553 9.467564621 34.75207884 1026.945064
9/13/2014   20.50534192 9.081091137 34.77935638 1027.028736
```

I want this to be associated to:

```
    Date    seawater_pressure   seawater_temperature    seawater_conductivity   practical_salinity  density lat lon Years
9/12/2014 0:00  177.859887  4.574663842 3.307338475 34.90723316 1028.476924 59.97533    -39.48183   2014.697222
9/12/2014 0:03  214.3598333 4.397781667 3.292384278 34.89887436 1028.659543 59.97533    -39.48183   2014.697222
9/12/2014 0:06  264.5863333 4.208137222 3.276747278 34.88825043 1028.905126 59.97533    -39.48183   2014.697222
9/12/2014 0:09  314.3161111 4.1242  3.271341056 34.88661059 1029.14336  59.97533    -39.48183   2014.697222
9/13/2014 21:00 2608.358764 1.83854382  3.163967753 34.87050646 1039.841076 59.97533    -39.48183   2014.7
9/13/2014 21:03 2571.051778 2.073876111 3.1833685   34.87381988 1039.643173 59.97533    -39.48183   2014.7
9/13/2014 21:06 2520.0315   2.334582222 3.204682722 34.87920389 1039.3818   59.97533    -39.48183   2014.7
9/13/2014 21:09 2469.559944 2.569326667 3.224910833 34.89808956 1039.136967 59.97533    -39.48183   2014.7
9/13/2014 21:12 2419.662011 2.67413743  3.23247419  34.90147888 1038.90175  59.97533    -39.48183   2014.7
```

I have a lot of data. Code below is messing with split but I am thinking the days since filter will work a lot better

```
import os
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
import re, time, random 

data = '''Date          pressure    temperature          density
9/12/2014 9:00     170            4.0                1028
9/12/2014 10:00    368            4.2                1028.5
9/12/2014 11:00    368            4.2                1028.5'''
da = [[i for i in re.split("[ ][ ]+", l)] for l in data.split("\n")]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(da[1:], columns=da[0])
data='''Date        pressure      temperature           density
9/12/2014 9:00  177.859887      4.574663842         1028.477
9/12/2014 9:01  214.3598333     4.397781667         1028.66
9/12/2014 9:55  264.5863333     4.208137222         1028.905
9/12/2014 10:01  314.3161111     4.1242              1029.143
9/12/2014 10:02  363.8005587     4.02983352          1029.377'''
da = [[i for i in re.split("[ ][ ]+", l)] for l in data.split("\n")]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(da[1:], columns=da[0])

df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.Date, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", utc=True)
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.Date, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", utc=True)
df3 = df1.join(df2.resample("1min").pad(), rsuffix="_hourly")
df3
```

Comment: If i am understanding correctly, you want to associate `daily averaged data` to the `daily minute data`, Right?

Comment: Yeah that's right! I want to do that to calculate the anomaly with the daily data

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you are looking for but it might help.

```
data = '''Date          pressure    temperature          density
9/12/2014        170            4.0                1028
9/13/2014     368            4.2                1028.5
9/14/2014    369            4.4                1030.5'''
da = [[i for i in re.split("[ ][ ]+", l)] for l in data.split("\n")]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(da[1:], columns=da[0])


data='''Date        pressure      temperature           density
9/12/2014 9:00  177.859887      4.574663842         1028.477
9/12/2014 9:01  214.3598333     4.397781667         1028.66
9/13/2014 9:55  264.5863333     4.208137222         1028.905
9/13/2014 10:01  314.3161111     4.1242              1029.143
9/14/2014 10:02  363.8005587     4.02983352          1029.377'''
da = [[i for i in re.split("[ ][ ]+", l)] for l in data.split("\n")]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(da[1:], columns=da[0])

df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.Date)
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.Date)
df3 = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2.rename(columns={'Date':'date'}), left_on='Date', right_on='date', direction='nearest', suffixes=['_minute','_daily'])
df3['date'] = df3.date.dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
df3['Date'] = df3.Date.dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

print(df3)
```

**Output**

```
               Date pressure_minute temperature_minute density_minute        date pressure_daily temperature_daily density_daily
0  09/12/2014 09:00  177.859887      4.574663842        1028.477       09/12/2014  170            4.0               1028        
1  09/12/2014 09:01  214.3598333     4.397781667        1028.66        09/12/2014  170            4.0               1028        
2  09/13/2014 09:55  264.5863333     4.208137222        1028.905       09/13/2014  368            4.2               1028.5      
3  09/13/2014 10:01  314.3161111     4.1242             1029.143       09/13/2014  368            4.2               1028.5      
4  09/14/2014 10:02  363.8005587     4.02983352         1029.377       09/14/2014  369            4.4               1030.5
```